# Is there a bpy.data.objects equivalent of bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply?

Tags: python, scripting, interface, node-editor

I'm trying to use Blender without invoking the GUI. How do you invoke the bpy.ops functions without a GUI? Is there a bpy.data.objects equivalent of by.ops.object.modifier_apply for instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no single low-level command that does this like the `bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply` operator, but this is possible without operators.

You can do this by using the [to_mesh](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Object.html?highlight=to_mesh#bpy.types.Object.to_mesh) method, which generates a new version of the object's mesh data, if you wish - with modifier's applied.

In this example I'm generating a version of the mesh data with modifier's applied, and assigning it directly back into the source object's data.

This updates the mesh geometry, but doesn't remove the modifier (since we simply generated a *copy*, and haven't actually applied the modifier yet).

So eventually all we need to do is to remove the modifier using the `object.modifiers.remove(modifier)` method.

```
import bpy

obj        = bpy.context.object
myModifier = obj.modifiers['Subsurf']

# Apply modifier to existing object data
obj.data = obj.to_mesh( 
    apply_modifiers = True, 
    scene           = bpy.context.scene, 
    settings        = 'PREVIEW' 
)

# Remove modifier from modifier's list
obj.modifiers.remove( myModifier )
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This work fine if I use Blender with a GUI, but not without. This simple script: `import bpy

bpy.data.images.load("test.jpg")
bpy.data.textures['displaceImage'].image = bpy.data.images['test.jpg']
bpy.ops.export_mesh.stl(filepath="test.stl", use_mesh_modifiers=True )
` works as well with a GUI, but not without. This puzzles me since there is no reference to a context in it.

Comment: or use `modifiers.clear()` to remove all modifiers

Comment: Not sure I understood. This didn't work for you? By the way you can use either method (mine or the simple apply_modifier operator) with or without a UI, it's simply a matter of context for using the operator (mainly have the object whose modifiers you want to apply selected and active).

Comment: Here is how I'm invoking the scripts: "blender 4x4UVSquare.blend -d -P 'Displace.py'" -> This invocation writes a displaced test.stl object. "blender 4x4UVSquare.blend --background -d -P 'Displace.py'" -> this invocation write a smooth, un-displaced test.stl

Comment: Can you add the error messages you get to your original question? And optimally your code or the relevant bits? I'm guessing this is a matter of not having a reference to the right object (if you're using the method specified above), or not having selected the object and made it active if you're using the apply_modifier operator.

Comment: Found the problem. Your solution works fine, as does my original script. I've been calling "blender" from outside the blender.app directory. I'm using a Mac. When I run the scripts from the "blender.app/Contents/MacOS" directory, everything works fine. I'll change my calling script to cd to this dir before running blender. Do you know why I need to call blender from the application directory?

Comment: Probably your 'Displace.py' file is located in this folder (or some other library you're importing from)? You can get around this by creating a symbolic link to your script from one of blender's system path folders. To find these folders, run blender from the UI, then type in the console: `import sys`, and then `sys.path`.